# How to compile the Roslyn project in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn

I need to compile Roslyn for adding c# 7.0 support to VS 2015. I know that I can add the Microsoft.Net.Compilers nuget package, but the editor show errors (compilation is fine).

I need it because the last year I compiled roslyn and I work with c# 7.0 features, mainly ValueTuple support, but I lost that features after a clean reinstallation, and I'm trying to recompile Roslyn and I have a lot of errors (probably now it need V2017).

Answer (score 1):

Yes; you need the latest version of Visual Studio (since the Roslyn codebase uses new language features).

For more info, see the [documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Building-Testing-and-Debugging) (and the instructions links).